# Difference between Apache CXF Maven distribution and CXF distribution

Tags: java, apache, maven, cxf

I need to use Apache CXF and Maven in my current project. 
When I downloaded CXF from the Apache site I noticed a set of Jars in the distribution.
But when I added the cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws dependency to pom.xml and issued an `mvn package` command, the lib folder had some different files, for e.g.
cxf-api-2.2.7.jar

What is the difference between the 2 distributions (if there is one)?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the downloaded distribution is not needed at all if using Maven.   The downloaded distro does provide some useful examples, etc... that can be helpful, but to build applications, you don't really need it.

The lib dir in the download, however, uses the "cxf-bundle" jar (renamed to just cxf-VERSION.jar) instead of the individual jars.   If you use maven, you likely will use the individual modules (like  cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws).   You can delete the lib/cxf-VERSION.jar and copy all the jars from  modules/*.jar to lib and pretty much accomplish the same thing with the download.   Thats just a BUNCH of jars though.

Note: you really should use CXF 2.6.2, not 2.2.7.  2.2.x is unsupported and has various security issues with it that are fixed in the newer versions.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. My apologies for not framing it correctly last time. Actually we are moving from a Maven setup to a non-Maven setup. We need the appropriate JARs to be referenced from a separate folder in the project (say ExternalJars).
So we were wondering which distribution should be available in this folder. As per your reply, I guess any one would do - either the 'cxf-bundle' from the lib folder in the download OR the individual JARs from the Modules folder in the download. Have I got it right? Thanks again.